# Comparing two columns across different sheets and returning a value from the 2nd sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

my tables look somewhat like this:

Table 1

| Name | Code |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | UH000511 |
| CBS | BY044551 |
| CLM | CZ004491 |
| LBU | UA955100 |

Table 2

| Company Name | Code |
| --- | --- |
| ABC Capital | UH000511 |
| Central Bank of Scotland | BY044551 |
| California Latitude Motors | CZ004491 |
| London Business Unit | UA955100 |

These tables are on different sheets, and I want to compare the code columns between the two sheets, and if they match, I want it to return the company name from Table 2 (of the second sheet). I have tried index/match but I'm getting nowhere so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you can use [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) to achieve this. You can define a value to look for (Code from table 1), where to look for it (code column from table 2) and what to return (company name from table 2)

Your equation would look like so providing your data is in columns A & B of sheets 1 & 2.

```
=XLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!A:A,"Not found",0)
```

Comment: Thank you @Crimsonfox, I ended up googling further and arrived at xlookup as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the Vlookup function, please refer to the following formula based on my sample.

`=VLOOKUP(B2,IF({1,0},$G$2:$G$5,$F$2:$F$5),2,0)`

[image]

If your Excel supports Xlookup function, the formula should be `=XLOOKUP(B2,$G$2:$G$5,$F$2:$F$5)`.

Comment: Thank you @Emily, I ended up googling further and arrived at xlookup as well.